# One way communication between two threads through Events

Tags: c++, multithreading, events

I have two threads that communicate in the following way: Thread A posts a message in a message queue and Thread B processes that message. Thread A has to wait until Thread B processes the message.

1. Thread A

   .........
   post a message on the message queue
   WaitForSingleObject (hEvent)
   Use the message processed information
   SetEvent(hEvent)
   .........
2. Thread B

   Process the message in the message queue
   SetEvent(hEvent)

Do you see any problems with the above code? Do I need to call ResetEvent() anywhere? 
Is the SetEvent() call required in Thread A or Thread A should only call WaitForSingleObject() and Thread B should only call SetEvent()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Thread A has to wait until Thread B processes the message" should make you rethink about necessity of using another thread.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But it is a bit of legacy code and the code comments state that all the processing of another COM server (that doesn't handle multi-threading) should be done in the same thread, so there is a separate thread just to process that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needn't call `ResetEvent` as long as the event is an ***AutoReset*** Event. This parameter is set in `CreateEvent`. I think your pseudocode is OK.

Comment: Sorry, this event is Manual. So do I need to call ResetEvent() after CreateEvent()?

Comment: @Harish: But why? In this situation you need an AutoReset Event. Do you use this event in other places too? Even if so, consider having a separate event for this part and make it AutoReset

Comment: Thanks, I changed the manual event to Auto event and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

A problem you will need to consider is the potential deadlock with this.  If Thread A has to wait until Thread B processes the event before continuing (and your WaitForSingleObject call does not have a useful timeout value passed to it), there is a chance that Thread B will never process the event and will lock Thread A.

Comment: Sorry for missing the deatils. Yes, Thread A Waits for few seconds and if the event is not set by Thread B, then it reports an error to the log file and carries on.